# libreoffice base - cli insertion of records?

Tags: command-line, libreoffice, database

I need to script the insertion of records into a database.  For this project (my first such), I'm using libreoffice Base with, for no particular reason, an HSQLDB back-end.  Is there a cli interface that would let me do that?

Comment: HSQLDB comes with a command-line SQL tool, so why not use that and bypass LibreOffice Base entirely?

Comment: If you're using an **embedded** HSQLDB, you'll need to convert it into a split database before accessing it using CLI tools.

Comment: @Jos - is that the package hsqldb-utils?  (I'm learning as I go.  I think the only reason to use Base is to access and make use of the DB after I've got the data in there.  It's all new, though!)

Comment: @tohuwawohu - Ahhh, thanks, I think!  Could you expand? :)

Comment: The SQL tool is part of the package `hsqldb-utils`. The command to start it is `hsqldb-sqltool`.

Comment: @tohuwawohu - Ok, yes.  I see that I set it up as embedded (that's the way Base shunts you unless you fight it); but I could have set it up as a server instead.  I'm not sure if there's some way I can convert (?)  I'm also still not clear what a "split database" is.  Input appreciated.

Comment: @tohuwawohu - ok, it looks like you're suggesting I need to [convert to server mode](http://ooo-forums.apache.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?t=58337&p=257542), which involves "[splitting](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=83&t=65980)".  That's a long process.  I'm just going to delete and recreate!  Thanks for the head's up!

Comment: @Jos - if you want to add your comment as an answer, I'll select it.  I think I know how to take the next step.  Thanks....

Comment: @Diagon: sorry for not responding - was away from pc. But you've found out yourself already :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to manipulate a HSQLDB database by means of scripts would be to use the tool `sqltool` provided in the package. You can do things like:

```
hsqldb-sqltool urlid --SQL="SQL statement 1; SQL statement 2; ..."
```

(where `urlid` is a file containing connection details), or read a bunch of SQL statements from a file, like this:

```
hsqldb-sqltool urlid file1.sql
```

NB: As @tohuwawohu points out, the database needs to be set up as a server to access it this way, rather than as "embedded", which is the first thing LibreOffice Base offers.